# Android support library not working (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

I am unable to open certain activity when starting a new android poroject. I have tried fixing the problem by installing the correct "Android Support Library" in the SDK Manager but the problem remains unsolved! Even the "Install/Upgrade" and "check again" functions in the [Install Dependencies Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJEbw.png) do not work! Btw I am using eclipse on a mac.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried Android Studio?

Comment: Yes but it runs very slowly. I only have 4g of ram and It's practically unusable!

Comment: I am using Android Studio on my MacBook Air with 4GB RAM and it works fine every time

Comment: Interesting. I just realized that I have 2GB of available space on my hard drive which is definitely not helping my case.. Thanks for the comment @A.A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio now is official IDE for android development provided by Google. The Android plugin for Eclipse doesn't have support anymore. Eclipse is setting up Andmore project: https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore to try to continue work on allowing Eclipse to build Android apss. But you should use Android Studio instead.

Comment: I see. well then It looks I'm going to have to trade my mac for a pc! thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use proxy:

```
windows-->preferences-->general-->network connections
```

Android SDK Manager:

```
Tools-->options-->enter your proxy
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am on a mac! Also I can see hat the the library has been downloaded, but the same "install dependancies screen" appears.

Comment: I do not have these options in the SDK Manager.